# CSS issue depending on Operating System

Tags: css

I am having an issue with CSS, on Windows and Linux it is OK, I get this

[image]

but in MAC, this what I get

[image]

as you can see, the cards with that red sign in the middle are not align.

the cards has a class, and here the CSS

```
.busterCards {
  border: 1px solid rgba(100, 100, 100, .6);
  background: white;
  margin-left: 1px;
  padding: 1px;
}
```

the red sign is just a unicode sign

which should be the problem here ?

Comment: Can you show us the markup?

Comment: Same browser between operating systems? If so, which one (+version)?

Comment: What happens when you give the cards an explicit `width:` ?

Comment: Which unicode sign are you using? Different operating systems may interpret, and have slight variations of font choices and representation of unicode characters.

Comment: Don't forget to specify the tested browsers when you add the relevant code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The unicode sign is obviously displayed with a different font, and thereby a liitle different size/spacing. Try use find a webfont that contains this sign and use that one.

edit: or use an image - that's safer, positionwise

Comment: it has sense. how do I look up for the proper webfont ?

Comment: Well, on this site http://www.fontsquirrel.com/  you can select first the font, the "glyphs" to see all characters it contains.